# Is it possible to invoke an Intellij IDE script externally i.e. via the command-line?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to write a script using the [Intellij IDE scripting console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-scripting-console.html), and invoke it externally using the command-line launcher e.g. `idea` for Intellij IDEA.

It looks like support was added in 2021.1 (see [YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245847)], but it might have been removed since(?).

I've tried to invoke the script using the following command but nothing happens; script does not seem to be executed, and no errors are logged.

```bash
# following command in YouTrack ticket referenced above
idea ideScript /path/to/script
```

These are the contents of the script, this works when run in the IDE.

```kotlin
# ide_script.kts
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages
import com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback

val project = ProjectManager.getInstance().defaultProject
val actionManager: ActionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
val action: AnAction = actionManager.getAction("NextTab")
val actionResult: ActionCallback = actionManager.tryToExecute(action, null, null, null, true)

Messages.showInfoMessage(project, actionResult.error ?: "Action success", "Action Result")
```

Ideally I'd also like to (if possible) parameterize the script e.g. pass in the action name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by wrapping the contents of the script in the following snippet:

```kotlin
IDE.application.invokeLater {
  // execute IDE action here
}
```

Then invoking the IDE script as you normally would `idea ideScript /path/to/script`.

I also created a shell script that handles accepts the action name as an argument; the full code is in the following [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/j4ckofalltrades/d7aac303466746e67287441e4fb9e0fe) for anyone that is interested.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define your flag

Try this:

```
idea --ideScript /path/to/script

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages
import com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback

val projectName = args[0]
val actionName = args[1]

val project = ProjectManager.getInstance().defaultProject
val actionManager: ActionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
val action: AnAction = actionManager.getAction(actionName)
val actionResult: ActionCallback = actionManager.tryToExecute(action, null, null, null, true)

Messages.showInfoMessage(project, actionResult.error ?: "Action success", "Action Result: $projectName")

idea --ideScript /path/to/script myProject myAction
```

Alternatively, you could try:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager
import com.intellij.openapi.ui.Messages
import com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback

val projectName = System.getenv("PROJECT_NAME")
val actionName = System.getenv("ACTION_NAME")

val project = ProjectManager.getInstance().defaultProject
val actionManager: ActionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
val action: AnAction = actionManager.getAction(actionName)
val actionResult: ActionCallback = actionManager.tryToExecute(action, null, null, null, true)

Messages.showInfoMessage(project, actionResult.error ?: "Action success", "Action Result: $projectName")

export PROJECT_NAME=myProject
export ACTION_NAME=myAction
idea --ideScript /path/to/script
```

This way the script will read the 'PROJECT_NAME' and 'ACTION_NAME' environment variables and use them within the script. This approach allows you to pass parameters to the script without modifying its contents.

Comment: > You didn't define your flag

From this [YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245847), it's meant to be used as a command e.g. `idea ideScript <files...>.